# Calculated field with if statements for years in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, pivot-table, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated fiel on excel in a pivot table to get some values depending on a year field. This is what i want to do: **If "Gestion" is 2023 then give me a particular field, if it's less than 2023 give me another.** This is my formula:

= IF(Gestion= 2023,'Aprobado US$', IF(Gestion< 2023,'Ejecucion_Acumulada US$','Vigente US$'))

For some reason that i don't understand, yet, i get just the values i wanted for the years before 2023 (2022-2018), for 2023 i get also 'Ejecucion_Acumulada US$'. It should give me 'Aprobado US$'.

[this is kind of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxwjQ.png)

As shown, i'm getting for all years 'Ejecucion_Acumulada US$ values, but i want 2023 with 'Aprobado US$' values.

Do you know how to get the proper values for 2023?

Comment: What kind of field is `Gestion`? it's being recognized properly as numeric? Any hidden decimals? any rounded value? You should add some data sample and expected output

Comment: Yes, Gestion is like 'year' and is recognized as numeric. There are no decimals. Let me edit the question to give more information